# Any bounded region $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with transitive automorphism group and sufficiently "smooth" edges is biholomorphic to the unit ball

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $G$ be a bounded region in $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. we have $G ≠ \emptyset$, and $G$ is open and connected), and let $G$ have a transitive automorphism group (that is, for each two points $z_1, z_2 \in G$, there exists a $\phi \in Aut(G)$ with $\phi(z_1) = z_2$, where $Aut(G)$ denotes the group of biholomorphic mappings from $G$ to $G$). In addition, let $G$ have "sufficiently smooth" edges: there exists an $a \in \partial G$ and an (open) neighborhood $U \subseteq G$ of $a$, so that $U \cap G$ is simply connected.

I now want to show that $G$ is biholomorphic to the open unit ball $B_1(0) = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$.

I believe what I need to do in this exercise is to show that not only $U \cap G$ is simply connected, but also $G$ itself: the rest then should follow more or less from the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). However, I don't know how I can show that. I think I must somehow "move" or "stretch" the simply connected set $U \cap G \subseteq G$ onto the other parts of $G$, to show that the rest of $G$ is simply connected too. But I'm not sure how to do that, seeing as we don't know too much about how the automorphisms of $G$ concretely look like, other than that there is always one that maps any point onto any other.

Comment: The information that G has a transitive automorphism group is redundant, since G is a manifold (You can look up Isotopy Lemma). What do you mean when you say there exists an open nbd. $U \subseteq G$ of $a$ ? Note that $a \notin G$.

Comment: I think by "automorphism" you mean a conformal self map.

Comment: @studiosus Yes, you're right. I've specified it in the question, sorry if it was too ambiguous.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha I mean a neighborhood of $a$ within $\mathbb{C}$. (Each open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $a$ also contains points from $G$, since $a \in \partial G$.) Also, thanks for the information about the Isotopy Lemma, I'll read into it. I just rephrased it like it was given to me, and the fact that this statement about $Aut(G)$ was explicitly stated makes me assume that I'll need it at some point in the proof.

Comment: @moran, what if you let G be an annulus ?

Comment: @SoumyaSinha Is that possible, with all the given preassumptions? I assumed that the goal of the exercise was to show that it isn't possible that $G$ "has holes", i.e. that I need to show that $G$ also must be simply-connected. Otherwise, I couldn't apply the Riemann mapping theorem at the end.

Comment: Yes, I think an annulus does constitute a counterexample.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha Ok, thanks. I must ask again though; are you sure that the Isotopy Lemma gives us that all (bounded) regions/domains in $\mathbb{C}$ have a transitive automorphism group when asking for a holomorphic structure (not just differentiable in the $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$-sense)? According to this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16685/exist-domains-in-complex-plane-with-only-trivial-automorphisms there exist open (and also bounded) domains in  $\mathbb{C}$ with a finite automorphism group (so it especially can't be transitive). Or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: @moran, Yes in the holomorphic sense the isotopy lemma is useless.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha ok, that's what I originally meant in the question; sorry if it was too ambiguous at first. I added it to the question.

Comment: @moran, rather surprisingly ( to me at least ), this indeed is true. Krantz gives quite a nice proof in the following - http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322791

Comment: @SoumyaSinha Thanks, that's a very nice proof indeed.

Comment: One more thing: The result that Krantz is proving does not need smooth boundary. The theorem is that if $U\subset {\mathbb C}$ is an open connected subset with transitive group of conformal automorphisms then either $U$ is simply connected or $U$ is the complement to a point in ${\mathbb C}$. However, I do not know any elementary proofs: The proof I have in mind uses the **uniformization theorem**, which is a harder form of the Riemann mapping theorem.